# Double RSA encryption on applet side (java card)

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, rsa, javacard

I'm trying to send a message from my applet to my terminal that is encrypted with both the private key of the applet and the public key of the terminal.

My code on the applet side currently looks like this:

```
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            byte[] temp = new byte[buf.length];
            cipher.init(priKeyC,Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
            outLength = cipher.doFinal(carID,(short)0,(short) 9,temp,(short)0);
            cipher.init(pubKeyT,Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
            outLength2 = cipher.doFinal(temp,(short)0,(short)outLength,buf,(short)0);

            apdu.setOutgoingLength(outLength2);
            apdu.sendBytes((short) 0,outLength2);
```

On the terminal my code looks like:

```
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, priKeyT);
        byte[] plainText = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pubKeyC);
        byte[] plainText2 = cipher.doFinal(plainText);

        return plainText2;
```

I checked if the private and public key of the terminal match and if the private and public key of the card match by using RSA only once. This works, both with terminal key pair and the card key pair, so the problem is definitely because of the double encryption.

I suspect something in the applet goes wrong when I try to copy the first encryption in temp. I've tried to store everything in buffer, but this also does not work.

```
            apdu.setOutgoing();
            cipher.init(priKeyC,Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
            outLength = cipher.doFinal(carID,(short)0,(short) 9,buf,(short)0);
            cipher.init(pubKeyT,Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);
            outLength2 = cipher.doFinal(buf,(short)0,(short)outLength,buf,(short)outLength);

            apdu.setOutgoingLength(outLength2);
            apdu.sendBytes((short) outLength,outLength2);
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Decryption error
```

The error appears at the first decryption.

Comment: `cipher.init(priKeyC,Cipher.MODE_ENCRYPT);` please **do not** encrypt with a private key. Use the `Signature` class. Encrypting with a private key is a sure way to shoot yourself in the foot.